# error while submitting corona app on app store

Tags: ios, coronasdk, app-store-connect

I am going to  update my  existing app on app store but it's giving me error of invalid bundle. Snapshot of error given below .[image]

Comment: Upgrade your Xcode to latest version and use iOS 7 SDK

Comment: ihave updated my xcode and it's xcode5

Comment: How about building with iOS 7 SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are using the latest Corona SDK. If you are using Graphics 2.0 the latest public build is the 2013.2100 and with Graphics 1.0 you should upgrade your code to 2.0 or use the 2014.1262 build.

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/29/apples-ios-7-submission-requirements/

Comment: Also just another tip, make sure your version numbers are the same. For instance if your build version is 1, make sure it's 1 on the app store, not 1.0